# Mvvm Unchecking a Checked Box in an underlying Listbox object

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have a listview that's item source is databound to an observable collection of a custom datatype. Each object in the list has the property DisplayName (string) and IsChecked (bool), among others. The data template essentially is :

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

When I check the boxes, I am able to determine, easily, the underlying items that now have been checked. However in the viewmodel, if i wish to uncheck an item, it does not seem to work going the other way.

I have NotifyProperty change implemented in the setter for the observable collection, but do i need to do something special for the bool?

In the Viewmodel, the following code is where I attempt to uncheck the checked checkboxes (as kind of a refresh after a command has run):

```
foreach (var bill in AllBills)
{
    bill.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Comment: You said you have implemented INofityOnPropertyChanged - do you also use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF CheckBox TwoWay Binding not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094679/wpf-checkbox-twoway-binding-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have NotifyProperty change implemented in the setter for the observable collection, but do i need to do something special for the bool?

Yes. When you give your collection property a new collection, you raise `PropertyChanged` for that property. What does that have to do with property values changing on an item *in* the collection? Nothing at all. When you set `IsChecked` on one of those items, is there any imaginable way for that code to hit the setter for your *collection* property? Nope.

Your items *in* the collection must themselves implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the setter for `IsChecked` must raise `PropertyChanged` when the value of `IsChecked` changes. If you did that for the collection property, I expect you already know how. But shoot me a comment if you run into any snags.

One of the tough parts of the WPF learning curve is developing a reliable intuitive sense of the borderline between things that just happen by secret framework rainbow pony magic, and things you have to do yourself. One spot on that borderline is where you're standing right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel, and are firing the event in IsChecked property, then just change your checkbox to:

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```